# Problems assigning a value to a 2 dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I can't seem to figure this out.
I can create and assign values to a two dimensional path array this way.

```
private static ArrayList<Path> ALIST_OF_FILES;
//i assign a list of file paths to ALIST_OF_FILES
//...
Path[][] data = new Path[][]{{ALIST_OF_FILES.get(0)},{ALIST_OF_FILES.get(1)},{ALIST_OF_FILES.get(2)},{ALIST_OF_FILES.get(3)},{ALIST_OF_FILES.get(4)}};
```

The above works. However when i do this, it throws an exception Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList

```
Path[][] data = new Path[ALIST_OF_FILES.size()][];
for (int i =0; i < ALIST_OF_FILES.size();i++){

 data[i][0]= ALIST_OF_Files.get(i);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you initialized the list?

Comment: Don't you think you'll need 2 for loops to do the 2D operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

> Path[][] data = new Path[ALIST_OF_FILES.size()][];

to

> Path[][] data = new Path[ALIST_OF_FILES.size()][1];

Answer (score 0):

You have not yet initialized your sub-arrays anywhere.

```
data[i][0] = ALIST_OF_Files.get(i);
```

At the above point *data[i]* is *null*;
In the for loop you should first initialize *data[i]* with a specific length